# If isset Session, add to $variable or $variable='0' write with one line

Tags: php

I have php code below and I want it to use **inline(one line)**. It should not repeat the $_SESSION name

```
$view = if (isset($_SESSION['Clients-view'])){
$view = $_SESSION['Cients-view'];
}
else{
$view = '0';
}
```

As you see it repeats **$view three times** and **$_SESSION two times**. I want it to write in a simple manner with single line.

Hope you understand the question.

Thank You,

SL

Comment: Ternary operator anyone...`?:`

Comment: `(isset($_SESSION['Clients-view']) ? $view = $_SESSION['Cients-view'] : $view = '0');`

Comment: Ouch... You were 5 seconds faster than me =D

Comment: @bcesars You also want `$view = isset(..) ? $_SESSION[..] : '0'`, not the assignment inside the operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
$view = isset($_SESSION['Clients-view']) ? $_SESSION['Cients-view'] : '0';
```

What I don't understand is, why in your code you have `$view = if (...` ? If do not have a return value.